# How to create subcommands for Ruby programs?

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am writing a Ruby CLI (Command Line Interface) program and I would like to be able to call subcommands similar to what rails does when you call `rails generate ...` or `rails server` etc. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the command line arguments and work with those. They are stored in the global array `ARGV`:

```
ARGV.each do|a|
  puts "Argv: #{a}"
end
```

That prints out the arguments sent to the ruby script

Answer (score 1):

The standard library's [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html) class exists specifically for handling command-line arguments like this. Here's [a tutorial](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/optionparser.htm). It should simplify your work considerably.